# Gradle - how to specify different Android *.apk build location for each flavor?

Tags: android, build, gradle

Is there a way to specify Android *.apk files build location other than ../build/apk/ ? Is it possible to specify different location for each flavour?

I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

thats work for me:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def outputName = // filename
    variant.outputFile = file(path_to_filename)
}
```

but "clean" task will not drop that apk, so you should extend clean task as below:

```
task cleanExtra(type: Delete) {
    delete outputPathName
}

clean.dependsOn(cleanExtra)
```

full sample:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

def outputPathName = "D:\\some.apk"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputFile = file(outputPathName)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

task cleanExtra(type: Delete) {
    delete outputPathName
}

clean.dependsOn(cleanExtra)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it tomorrow. If it works I will accept your response :)